# Map virtual directory to Azure AppService

Tags: azure, subdomain, azure-web-app-service, virtual-directory

We are building multi-tenant application where we have many different components like Web Site, two API sites, etc. Since, Azure does not support multi-level of sub-domain like ***.web.mydomain.com*** or **.api.mydomain.com**, we are thinking to have virtual directory for each component like ***.mydomain.com/web***, **.mydomain.com/api**.

Here, we will have tenant alias as sub-domain e.g. **tenant1.mydomain.com/web**, **tenant2.mydomain.com/web**.

How do I map virtual directory to Azure AppService (Website)?

Answer (score 0):

@Hitesh, you can add a CNAME record at your domain hosting provider like GoDaddy to map a wildcard domain to your Azure App Service. There is a [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2015/12/01/mapping-a-wildcard-domain-name-to-an-azure-app-services-web-app-website/) from MSDN
which introduce how to do it.

If you want to map different virtual directories to different App Services, you can [create an Azure Application Gateway using URL based routing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/application-gateway-create-url-route-arm-ps/) via Azure PowerShell with ARM to implement it.